# Adding a template typename to two template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have learned this code like inheritance by using template technique on C++. This code works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class Base {
public:
    explicit Base(const T& policy = T()) : m_policy(policy) {}
    void doSomething() 
    {
        m_policy.doA();
        m_policy.doB();
    }
private:    
    T m_policy;
};

class Implemented {
public:
    void doA() { cout << "A"; };
    void doB() { cout << "B"; };
};

int main() {
    Base<Implemented> x;
    x.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

However, is it possible to add arguments with new typename S in doA and doB? For example, this code doesn't work by type/value mismatch errors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < typename T, typename S >
class Base {
public:
    explicit Base(const T& policy = T()) : m_policy(policy) {}
    void doSomething() 
    {
        m_policy.doA(m_s);
        m_policy.doB(m_s);
    }
private:    
    T m_policy;
    S m_s;
};

template < typename S >
class Implemented {
public:
    void doA(S& s) { cout << "A" << s; };
    void doB(S& s) { cout << "B" << s; };
};

int main() {
    Base<Implemented, int> x;
    x.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

I guess I must let both class Base and Implemented know about an actual type of S at main(). How can I fix this issue? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Implemented was a class, you used a template parameter `T`. Now that Implmented is a template class, you need to use a so called template template parameter, like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template < template <class TS> class T, typename S >
class Base {
public:
    explicit Base(const T<S>& policy = T<S>()) : m_policy(policy) {}
    void doSomething() 
    {
        m_policy.doA(m_s);
        m_policy.doB(m_s);
    }
private:    
    T<S> m_policy;
    S m_s;
};

template < typename S >
class Implemented {
public:
    void doA(S& s) { cout << "A" << s; };
    void doB(S& s) { cout << "B" << s; };
};

int main() {
    Base<Implemented, int> x;
    x.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! At first, I thought I had to use template's template but I didn't know how I could write. This also works as well as the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
Base<Implemented, int> x;
```

`Implemented` is no longer a type, now you made it a template. But `Base` still expects a type - so give it one:

```
Base<Implemented<int>, int> x;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Barry. It completely works! If I use different types between type S of Base and type S of Implemented, it causes a compile error as I intended.